# Нужно ли ставить тире после имён?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Анна "–" моя девушка.

Саша "–" мой лучший друг.

В контексте представления человека кому-то.

И в подобных:
Александра Петровна "–" наш классный руководитель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенных случаях тире выполняет функцию связки:

> Тире, прежде всего, означает пропуски — пропуск связки в сказуемом,
> пропуск члена предложения в неполных предложениях и в предложениях с
> нулевым сказуемым, пропуск противительных союзов. Тире как бы
> компенсирует эти пропущенные слова, сохраняет принадлежащее им место,
> например:
>
> «Солотча — извилистая, неглубокая река» (К. Паустовский); — пропуск
> связки...
>
> *[[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)]*

*Саша [есть] мой лучший друг* — пропуск связки.

---

Кроме того, тире обозначает соединительную паузу:

> Тире в звучащей речи требует некоторого повышения голоса на
> предшествующем знаку ударном слове и **означает соединительную паузу**.
> Этот знак ставится с целью разъяснить то, что находится перед ним,
> противопоставить одно явление другому или подвести итог.
>
> *[Никольская С. Т. Техника речи (Методические рекомендации и упражнения
> для лекторов) ]*

Произносится:

*Саша [пауза] мой лучший друг.*

---

В данном случае тире нужно: оно в письменной речи показывает пропуск связки, а в устной — соединительную паузу.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 2):

1. В контексте **представления**  пауза особо **подчеркивается**, поэтому тире ставится обязательно. ***САша – мой лучший друг***. Или другой вариант: *Это Саша, мой лучший друг.*

Здесь мы сначала называем имя, а потом даем **характеристику** человека. Это **особый случай** в данной теме.

2. Что касается **общих правил**, то тире обычно ставится, но  возможны **исключения**: Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92 (примечание 1 к пункту 1)

**Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится: 1) в простых по составу предложениях РАЗГОВОРНОГО стиля речи: Моя мать инженер. Мой брат школьник.

Соответственно, вам придется решать вопрос о том, **какой у вас стиль речи.** В действительности этот вопрос не такой однозначный – дело даже не в стиле речи, а **в структуре предложения и ударениях**, например:
(1) *Мой отец инженЕр, а мама учИтельница*. Нет паузы и тире. (2) Сравнить: *МОй брат – физик, а твОй кто? Вряд ли он в таких вещах разбирается.* Здесь пауза и тире. В то же время в обоих случаях у нас **запись разговорной речи.**

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения в примерах.

Comment: А что, есть какие-то особенности постановки тире, связанные с именами?